How to use @Input @Output between two child components
I have two components - child1 and child2. How to achieve the below scenario using @Input and @Output component sharing.
Below is the sample code having two divs side by side in a single component.
But I need to achieve in a way wherein one div is in one component, and the other div in another component and pass the data between these 2 components.

<div class="parentDiv">
        <div class="parentBox1" (click)="movetoparentbox2(childBox1)" *ngFor=" let childBox1 of childArray">
            {{childBox1}}
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="parent2Div">
    
        <div class="parentBox2" (click)="movetoparentbox1(childBox2)"  *ngFor="let childBox2 of child2Array">
            {{childBox2}}
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './child1.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./child1.component.css']
    })
    export class Child1Component {
      childArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      child2Array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
      filtered!: any[];
    
      movetoparentbox2(name: any) {
        this.child2Array.push(name);
        this.filtered = this.childArray.filter((el) => el != name);
        console.log("filtered", this.filtered)
        this.childArray = this.filtered;
      }
    
      movetoparentbox1(name: any) {
        this.childArray.push(name);
        this.filtered = this.child2Array.filter((el) => el != name);
        this.child2Array = this.filtered;
      }
    }

.parentDiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: brown;
    float: left;
    margin: 30px;
}

.parent2Div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
    float:left;
    margin: 30px;

}
.parentBox1 {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: blueviolet; 
   margin: 15px;
   padding: 15px;
   float: left;
}

.parentBox2{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green; 
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
}


For what you want to do I would use an Angular Service, inject it into both components and EventEmitters inside the Service, to which your components can subscribe to...

Could you explain more with a sample code?

Input and Output only works when the components have a parent-child relationship
You can use a service or put the logic in the parent (the arrays belongs to the parent, the functions moveToparenets in the parent also...)
And you pass as input to your child the arrays
.....child-component...

@Input() childArray:any[]
@Output() move:EventEmitter<string>=new EventEmitter<string>()

click(name:string){
   this.move.emit(name)
}

